# NA vector in language R

Tags: r, na

How I can identify if a resulting vector from one computation is full of the NA values?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via `all(is.na(x))`:

```
R> x1 <- 1:3
R> all(is.na(x1))
[1] FALSE
R> x2 <- x1 * NA
R> all(is.na(x2))
[1] TRUE
R>
```